# In App Purchase purchase very slow after restoring

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a problem when I restore previous purchases (by using `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`) and then I purchase immediately (`[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment]`). I have to wait for long time until showing alert from AppStore.

I can tell it seems to be calling this `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction]` in `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`, which makes it slow. When I comment this out it works faster.

According to Apple's In-App Purchase Guide I should call `finishTransaction` every time when the observer calls `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions`. 
How can I figure this problem out?

Thank you very much